# Would this code to add a String object to a binary tree work? How would I debug this data structure?

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm not sure if this add method will work because I don't really know how I would check to make sure it's been added to the right spot.

1.Is there anything wrong with this method?
2.How would one go about testing binary tree data structures (if object was added to proper spot)?
3.Can this be done with recursion?
4.If yes, would it be better to use a loop or recursion?

```
public boolean add(String item) {
    Node tempNode = this.root;

    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node(item);
        return true;
    }

    while (tempNode.getItem().compareTo(item) == 0 || tempNode.getItem().compareTo(item) > 0 || tempNode.getItem().compareTo(item) < 0) {
        if (tempNode.getItem().compareTo(item) == 0) {
            if (tempNode.getLeftChild() == null) {
                tempNode.setLeftChild(new Node(item));
                return true;
            } else if (tempNode.getRightChild() == null) {
                tempNode.setRightChild(new Node(item));
                return true;
            } else if (tempNode.getLeftChild() != null) {
                tempNode = tempNode.getLeftChild();
            } else if (tempNode.getRightChild() != null) {
                tempNode = tempNode.getRightChild();
            }
        } else if (tempNode.getItem().compareTo(item) > 0) {
            if (tempNode.getLeftChild() == null) {
                tempNode.setLeftChild(new Node(item));
                return true;
            } else {
                tempNode = tempNode.getLeftChild();
            }
        } else {
            if (tempNode.getRightChild() == null) {
                tempNode.setRightChild(new Node(item));
                return true;
            } else {
                tempNode = tempNode.getRightChild();
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: 'tempNode.getItem().compareTo(item) == 0 || tempNode.getItem().compareTo(item) > 0 || tempNode.getItem().compareTo(item) < 0'  must be true, it is as well as while(true)

Comment: Shoud I make it while(tempNode.getLeftChild() != null || tempNode.getRightChild() != null )? or just while(tempNode != null)

Comment: I think while true is ok, because you can jump while loop by return statement.

Comment: Isn't while true considered poor programming style(?)

Comment: maybe, but in your code you must jump *while loop* by *return statement* rather than the *condition of while*.

Answer (score 0):

I see two errors in your code.

1. Your while statement will become an infinite loop regardless of the input, you can just remove it fortunately as your internal if statements already cover every case.
2. I see that you check root to see if it is null after you have already made a copy of it. If you change the value of root after making a copy, that copy is still null (assuming root was null before). I don't think this is what you intended.

Second, the best way to test a binary tree is to just try adding stuff to it and print it out by walking the tree. (See in order tree traversal - a type of recursion)

Third, all things can be done with recursion, in fact it would be difficult to do tree traversal with a loop.

Comment: as for the second, if **OP** change the value of root the next statement is **return**, so I think it is ok.

Comment: Ah, you are right. The ordering just triggered my bug senses I guess.

Answer (score 0):

> how I would check to make sure it's been added to the right spot.

---

you can `make breakpoint` after invoke `add` or you can `make breakpoint` at `all return statement` in `method` then you can see the `childs of root` and `childs of their child`. In this way, you can view the whole tree, and check whether the node you insert is on the `true postion`.
as for your code, there exist some little flaw.

***first*** `tempNode.getItem().compareTo(item) == 0 || tempNode.getItem().compareTo(item) > 0 || tempNode.getItem().compareTo(item) < 0` must be true 
 ***second*** as for this code segment:

```
     if (tempNode.getLeftChild() == null) {
            tempNode.setLeftChild(new Node(item));
            return true;
        } else if (tempNode.getRightChild() == null) {
            tempNode.setRightChild(new Node(item));
            return true;
        } else if (tempNode.getLeftChild() != null) {
            tempNode = tempNode.getLeftChild();
        } else if (tempNode.getRightChild() != null) {
            tempNode = tempNode.getRightChild();
        }
```

---

the last `else if` may never be `executed` that is to say it is as well as below code:

```
   if (tempNode.getLeftChild() == null) {
            tempNode.setLeftChild(new Node(item));
            return true;
        } else if (tempNode.getRightChild() == null) {
            tempNode.setRightChild(new Node(item));
            return true;
        } 
        else{
             tempNode = tempNode.getLeftChild();
        }
    }
```